# Dynamically allocated string from command line argument

Tags: c, string, malloc

I'm looking to process a string passed via a command line argument with a for loop in C. I'm wondering if this would be the correct way.

```
main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char * somestring;
    somestring = malloc( (strlen(argv[1]) + 1) * sizeof(char) );
    somestring = argv[1];

       ...
}
```

or would C allocate the appropriate memory if I did:

```
char * somestring;
somestring = argv[1];
```

Comment: Why not use `strcpy`? Why C will allocate memory for you if you don't ask for it?

Comment: It depends. Do you want to be able to modify `somestring` and keep original argument intact? Do you just want to use (without modifying) an argument?

Comment: I just want to process it character by character with a for loop.

Comment: If you just want to process the argv[1] element, you can do so immediately, there is no need to copy it first. Only if you want to change it, then it would be advisable to make a copy (strcat, even easier: strdup() - this does the malloc *and* the copy)

Comment: `malloc` creates the space on the heap to store it. `strcpy` would copy that string to the locations you malloced

Comment: @jcoppens is correct. You can loop over each character in argv[1] directly. You can even modify them if you so choose. The C99 standard even makes it clear that argv strings are modifiable (mutable): `The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy an argument in your own allocated memory then you have to write

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[1])
{
    char * somestring;
    somestring = malloc( strlen( argv[1] ) + 1 );
    strcpy( somestring, argv[1] );

       ...
}
```

otherwise statement

```
    somestring = argv[1];
```

results in a memory leak.

Also do not forget to free the memory when it will not be needed any more.

Take into account that though this record

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[1])
```

is valid it is better to write

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
```

because your intention by specifying `char * argv[1]` is not clear

Comment: On the other hand, not `malloc`ing at all and doing `somestring = argv[1]` is totally fine, if you don't need a copy.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to preserve a transient string then yes you need to allocate memory, copy it into the new buffer (via `strcpy`-like function) and latter deallocate that buffer.

But in this case, the command line arguments are not transient. They are available for the whole lifetime of the process. Therefore it is enough to just remember the pointer to them. So something like this would be enough:

```
const char* firstParameter = nullptr;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) firstParameter = argv[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt of all this is a wrong way of copying a string into another string.
You have done memory allocation correcly but your method of copying a string into another is wrong. You have allocated memory for string and collected its address into somestring. Now you are assigning argv[1] to it which is address of command line argument vector which is 2D array actually. So you should use strcpy() to copy string.

Or if you want just base address of string use char pointer instead and assign argv[1] to it. But it is of no use.

P.S. passing command line argument like you are doing is not recommended as all arguments are stored in argument vector argv which is 2D array. So if you are passing only one string then it is okay but if you are passing more than one strings then use char **argv instead.

Comment: What do you mean by `argv` being a 3D array? Never heard of that idea. Also you don't seem to be aware that for function parameters `char *argv[1]`, `char*argv[]` and `char**argv` are all the same.

Comment: But if you are storing your argument only in argv[1] then how will you able to use next argument passed?

Comment: You are not "storing" an argument in `argv[1]`. You urgently have to read up how "array" parameters for functions are interpreted. The C FAQ should be a good starting point.

Comment: And sorry, wrongly written. I hadnt noticed that. Its 2d array actually. When you pass multiple arguments how are you able to get different arguments? By dereferencing it once. Now if you want to get only first character of 2nd argument how will you get that? By argv[1][0] ri8?

Comment: Still not right, `argv` is not a 2D array. It is a pointer to pointers to `char`.

Comment: And the comments to an answer that you gave is certainly not the right place to get answers to your very basic C programming questions. Please read on about these questions, there is a lot of documentation out there, including on SO.

Answer (score 0):

A good way would be allocating the memory for the pointer and use `strcpy` function to copy the contents.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char *somestring;
    if(argv[1] == NULL)
    {
        puts("Argument 1 is not specified.");
        exit(1);
    }
    somestring = malloc( strlen(argv[1])+1 );
    strcpy(somestring, argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n",somestring);
    return 0;
}
```

Also before allocating the memory for pointer, first check if `argv[1]` is not `NULL`.